# How to use Secured Web Sockets with mosquitto and JS?

Tags: javascript, websocket, mqtt, mosquitto, paho

I have a frontend in JS connecting to a MQTT server ([`mosquitto`](https://mosquitto.org/)) with the help of the [Paho JavaScript Client](https://www.eclipse.org/paho/clients/js/). This works fine, I can publish and listen to topics.

I now would like to promote the Web Sockets connection to a secured one.

To this, I added to my `/etc/mosquitto/mosquitto.conf` the entries for `certfile` and `keyfile`:

```
pid_file /var/run/mosquitto.pid
persistence true
persistence_location /var/lib/mosquitto/
log_dest file /var/log/mosquitto/mosquitto.log
include_dir /etc/mosquitto/conf.d
listener 1883
listener 1884
protocol websockets
# above is the working, non-wss configuration
certfile /etc/mosquitto/wildcard.crt
keyfile /etc/mosquitto/wildcard.key
```

Provided that this is the right configuration, **how can I create a client in JS which would take into account the secure connection?** For the existing one, I have

```
client = new Paho.MQTT.Client("10.10.10.10", 1884, Math.random().toString(16).substring(7))
```

and do not see any other configuration to be passed here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [docs](http://www.eclipse.org/paho/files/jsdoc/Paho.MQTT.Client.html#connect)

You have several options:

1. the `host` when declaring a new client can be a URI rather than just a ip/hostname

   ```
   client = new Paho.MQTT.Client("wss://10.10.10.10:1884", Math.random().toString(16).substring(7));
   ```
2. You can use the `useSSL` flag in the `client.connect(options)` options object.

   ```
   client.connect({
     useSSL: true
    });
   ```

Comment: I tried the first option but it was ultimately used as `ws://wss://10.10.10.10:1844/mqtt` which is incorrect. I missed the second option in the doczs - thanks!

Comment: Then that's a bug, you should raise an issue (or check you have the latest version)